# Changing multiple data frame column titles in r

Tags: r, dataframe, names

The program that I am running creates three data frames using the following code:

```
datuniqueNDC <- data.frame(lapply(datlist, function(x) length(unique(x$NDC))))
datuniquePID <- data.frame(lapply(datlist, function(x) length(unique(x$PAYERID)))
datlengthNDC <- data.frame(lapply(datlist, function(x) length(x$NDC)))
```

They have outputs that look like this:

```
  X182L X178L X76L
1   182   178   76

  X34L X31L X7L
1   34   31   7

  X10674L X10021L X653L
1   10674   10021   653
```

What I am trying to do is combine the rows together into one data frame with the desired outcome being:

```
        X      Y    Z
1     182    178   76
2      34     31    7
3   10674  10021  653
```

but the rbind command doesn't work due to the names of all the columns being different.  I can get it to work by using the colnames command after creating each variable above, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way to accomplish this by using one of the apply commands or something similar.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe you should give example of what `datlist` looks like.

Comment: `datlist` is a list of three different data frames of varying number of rows and 7 columns.  The code above is used to extract similar values from all three data frames.

Comment: try: `sapply(dataList, function(x) c(length(unique(x$NDC)), length(unique(x$PAYERID)), length(x$NDC)))`

Answer (score 1):

one way, *since evreything seems to be a numeric*, would be this:

```
mylist <- list(dat1,dat2,dat3) 
# assuming your three data.frames are dat1:dat3 respectively

 do.call("rbind",lapply(mylist, as.matrix))
#     X182L X178L X76L
#[1,]   182   178   76
#[2,]    34    31    7
#[3,] 10674 10021  653
```

basically this works because your data are matrices not dataframes, then you only need to change names once at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should at least simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Since the functions you use in you `lapply` calls are scalars, it would be easier if you use `sapply`. `sapply` returns vectors which you can `rbind`

```
datuniqueNDC <- sapply(datlist, function(x) length(unique(x$NDC)))
datuniquePID <- sapply(datlist, function(x) length(unique(x$PAYERID))
datlengthNDC <- sapply(datlist, function(x) length(x$NDC))
dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(datuniqueNDC,datuniquePID,datlengthNDC))
names(dat) <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

Another solution is to calculate all three of your statistics in one function:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(sapply(datlist, function(x) {
    c(length(unique(x$NDC)), length(unique(x$PAYERID), length(x$NDC))
}))
names(dat) <- c("x", "y", "z")
```